# Firefox webextension onclose of the software handler

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I want to create a firefox webextension that convert the closing button of firefox with  minimizing operation. 
Does Anybody know the handler for the closing operation (for all the browser not only a tab) and command to force minimizing it?

Answer (score 0):

It is no possible at the moment. WebExtensions have a very restricted access to Firefox UI.